# QGIS raster: Which band is which?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have an image from a Canon SD110 NIR camera, which I can import in RAW (CR2) into QGIS.

However, I am finding it difficult to know which band represents which 'colour' output.

According to the manufacturer it provides 'green, red and nir'.

Do those bands hold true for any software?

Firstly, QGIS loads 4 bands!The fourth band has a load of zeroes (looking at the xml file you can produce) bar one number at the end of the array of values it gives. Can I safely ignore this?

Secondly, so can I assume Band1 is green, Band2, red, and Band 3 the NIR in the same sequence as quoted by the manufacturer?

I know QGIS is not really an appropriate piece of software for this, just playing!

Comment: You will need a pre-process like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnRFXMCI1p4 before using qgis (photoshop/globalmapper example)